# Not getting any errors but page not rendering with render_template in my flask app

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, flask

The problem I am having is the page is not being rendered. It just returns to the default index.html and not response.html

I have created a flask app using python on the back end and javascript/jquery/ajax on the front end. However whenever I try to return a view in the template I get no errors (either in the console or in the cmd window) and the page doesnt render. Any help with this would be appreciated. Here is the code:

here is index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Local Sales Scraper</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css') }}">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

  </head>
<body>

  <div class="topnav">
    <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <form class = "form" action="parse_data" method="POST">
      <input id ="textbox" name="textbox" type="text" placeholder="Search..">

    </form>
  </div>
  <form class = "form2" action="parse_data" method="POST">
  <h3> Price Range </h3>
  <input id ="start" name="start" type="number" placeholder="Start..">
  <input id ="end" name="end" type="number" placeholder="End..">
  <input type="checkbox" id="sort"> sort lowest to highest price<br>
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
</br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="Ebay" value="Ebay" class="chk"> Search Ebay<br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="Craigslist" value="Craigslist" class="chk"> Search Craigslist<br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="Letgo" value="Letgo" class="chk"> Search Letgo<br>

  <h2 id="search-query"></h2>
  <h2 id="search-results"> search results: </h2>


<script>



//alert(value);
$("button").click(function (e) {

  //alert(checkedIds.join(", "));
    //alert("button clicked and checked");
    e.preventDefault();
    var sorted = $("#sort").val();
    var search = $("#textbox").val();
    var startPrice = $('#start').val();
    var endPrice = $('#end').val();
    //alert(sorted);
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "parse_data",
      data: JSON.stringify({"search" : search, "startPrice" : startPrice, "endPrice" : endPrice, "sorted" : sorted}),
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      success: function(data){


        //alert(JSON.parse(data));

      }
    });

});




</script>
</body>
</html>
```

here is response.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Flask app</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css') }}">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

  </head>
<body>

  <div id="div1">
  <p id="p1"></p>
  <p id="p2"></p>
  </div>


  <script>
var s = {{ data|tojson }};
var s = JSON.parse(jsonz);

var i;
for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
  var header = document.createElement("h2");
  var para = document.createElement("p");
  var a = document.createElement('a');

  var linkText = document.createTextNode("here is the link to the item");
  a.href = s[i].product_link;
  var price = document.createTextNode(s[i].product_price);
  var node = document.createTextNode(s[i].product_name);
  para.appendChild(node);
  a.appendChild(linkText);
  header.appendChild(price);

  var element = document.getElementById("div1");
  element.appendChild(para);
  element.appendChild(a);
  element.appendChild(header);



//  a.title = "title";




  }
  </script>
</body>
```

and app.py

```
from scraper import scrape
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify, make_response, request
import json
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route("/parse_data", methods=['POST'])
def parse_data():

    data = request.get_json()

    #print data


    #search = json.loads(search)
    scrapedData = json.dumps(scrape(data))
    #entries = jsonify({'name' : entries})
    #print scrapedData

    return render_template('index.html', data= scrapedData)




if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the route you are trying to visit that doesn't render? I already see a problem with your template and your index route. in your HTML template you are trying to parse `var s = {{ data|tojson }};` but in your index route, data is not returned with render_template. Also, you are trying to parse `JSON.parse(jsonz)` but I dont see `jsonz` defined anywhere in your code. Also your index.html does not conform to HTML structure. It is like you places 2 HTML pages inside one page.

You can only have one `<html>` tag per page, one `<head>` tag per page and one `<body>` tag per page. You have 2 of each and that is the reason why the page doesn't get rendered

**UPDATE**

The reeason for this is because you are not rendering response.html in your code. You are rendering index.html

Your `parse_data()` should render `response.html` and **not** `index.html`

```
@app.route("/parse_data", methods=['POST'])
def parse_data():

    data = request.get_json()

    #print data


    #search = json.loads(search)
    scrapedData = json.dumps(scrape(data))
    #entries = jsonify({'name' : entries})
    #print scrapedData

    return render_template('response.html', data= scrapedData)
```

**UPDATE #2**

When you are making an ajax call on button click, You are sending a request to `parse_data()` and waiting for a response. You cannot expect `parse_data()` to render any html since it is supposed to return a response to your ajax call. In your case, It will return the whole html as a string 
 as a response to your ajax call and will not render the template as you would expect it since the request was made with ajax. If you will be more specific with what you are trying to achieve I can try and provide you with sample code.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I updated the code to define `jsonz` in `JSON.parse(jsonz)` I also updated to include index.html. I am trying to render response.html in this code: `return render_template('response.html', data= scrapedData)`

Comment: I also noticed you have 2 html tags and 2 body tags as well as 2 head tags in your index.html. I have updated my answer as well. You can only have one html, head, body tag per page

Comment: woops the only reason it has two html tags is because i forgot to separate index.html and response.html in my post. I have corrected it

Comment: Please see my updated answer. You are trying to render index.html instead of response.html and that is why it returns to index

Comment: but as you can see it does try to render 'response.html' unless I am seeing something weird

Comment: Based on the code sample you provided, There is no way for it to even try to render response.html since your are instructing both of your views `index()` and `parse_data()` to render `index.html`.from your ajax call, the `parse_data()` code will run but notice how at the end, you are rendering `index.html` instead of rendering `response.html. See my update #2 in the answer